# detect outgoing/incoming number android 5.1.1 lollipop programmatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Trying to detect outgoing or incoming number on (Lollipop 5.1.1) OnePlus two oxygen os

tried many ways with googling but cant success

```
String number = intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
```

Permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

using the bellow code for getting incoming or outgoing number

```
public class callRecorderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static String TAG = "CallRecorderReceiver";
    private Context mContext = null;
    static long start_time, end_time;
     String callType = "";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.mContext = context;
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String extraState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Action:" + action);
        Log.d(TAG, "ExtraState:" + extraState);

         String number = intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
            if (number == null || number.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            }

        if (extraState.equalsIgnoreCase("OFFHOOK")) {

            if (number != null && !number.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                number = number;
                temp_data.current_number = "" + number;
            }

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {

            if (number != null && !number.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
               callType = "outgoing";
                if (!((number.contains("*") && number.contains("#")) ))) {
                    Log.d("outgoing CallTo:", number);

                }
                            }
        } else if (action.equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
            try {
                String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number");

                if (intent.getStringExtra("state").equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                    Log.d("ringing ", "incomingNumber " + incomingNumber);
                } else if (intent.getStringExtra("state").equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

                    Log.d("idle ", incomingNumber);
                } else if (intent.getStringExtra("state").equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)))) {
                    Log.d("State:", "current_state:" + temp_data.current_state);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: did you got any solution. I am facing same issue.

Comment: Nope, now this work is handed over to another guy, but still, I want to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

check this link....[http://bitgriff.blogspot.in/2013/01/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone.html] i wish it will hwlp you

Comment: you can only handle it by broadcast receiver . no one another method to do this. it helps in my case. try to do as per requirement it will definitely can be done

Answer (score 0):

So reason is onReceive() method not invoke, First check the version of the device if the device is greater than lolipop, please go to settings > apps > current working app > give permission for phone then it will work for you.